# Weird straight lines in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, nvidia-graphics-card

In my Chrome web browser (58.0.3029.110 and previous) on some pages there are visible weird straight lines. I am using Windows 10 x64, nvidia gtx 970. This happens only in Chrome.
I am looking for any explanation.

This screenshots show my problem:

[image: Mixcloud screenshot]
[image: Google Presentations]

Comment: Guest profile and incognito mode didn't help. http://c97.pl/pliki/chrome-problem/chrome3.png

Comment: @McDonald's look at my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I hate answering my own questions. Second, I found two solutions to my problem.

First one is to turn off hardware acceleration. To do so, go to Settings > Advanced settings > "Use hardware acceleration when available" and uncheck it.
This is weaker solution because you have to disable whole hardware acceleration.

The second solution is to disable only hardware rasterization. Go to url chrome://flags/ find "GPU rasterization" and set it to "Disabled". This solution is better, it disables only a small part of hardware acceleration.

[image: GPU rasterization disabled screenshot]

In both cases those weird lines were removed.

Thanks Nihan J Co. because you gave me some leads on this.

Comment: I experienced the same issue on a 2019 16" MacBook Pro (macOS 10.15.4) with an AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8GB under Chrome 80.0.3987.163. When the problem occurred particular tabs would contain hundreds of angled blue lines sometimes overlapping. This would distort the page so badly nothing could be read. Once a page rendered this way it seemed to be persistent even after process exits. So far, I have been able to achieve a fix by disabling "Out of process rasterization" and leaving GPU rasterization and hardware acceleration enabled. If this changes, I will provide an update.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly this Chrome/Chromium rasterization bug, which appears to be specific to certain NVidia GPUs.
A solution is:

cleaning up the svg file may solve the issue.
 SVGO https://github.com/svg/svgo